# How to display website.com/a/b in the address bar instead of website.com/?x=a&y=b

Tags: get

It's possible to display parametres as a folders (order counts). How to do that?

As result, `website.com/?x=a&y=b&z=c` would look like `website.com/a/b/c` - shorter and easier.

Does it depend on server hosting settings? Should I contact hosting customer support about this question? Or, that's just a php issue (some options of $_GET method)?

Thank you.
P.S. How to differ `website.com/?x=a` and `website.com/?y=b` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Whererver the site is hosted, if it is a IIS server with sql server. The site's domain name and other 
FURL details will be held in a table on the database. 
This will need to be updated. and restart the server. 
Do you have control of this database locally?

With regard to PHP. You can chance the httpd settings and upload this to the server/host.